# Access each row of a matrix and apply to function

Tags: r

I have this matrix in r which has two columns, shape and scale.

Now i have 10000 rows, what i need is to apply this code below:

```
rw <- rweibull(10, shape=, scale=)
```

I need to loop through each row of the matrix in order to calculate the rw.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Output for `dput(head(mat, 10))`

```
structure(c(0.953866743, 0.939544872, 0.88055226, 0.937567804, 
0.902443856, 0.969984293, 0.953468872, 0.929905045, 0.889375987, 
0.910115923, 0.152704576, 0.168592082, 0.13059434, 0.153850643, 
0.172734767, 0.162162429, 0.172533372, 0.160826152, 0.190843263, 
0.156289128), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("shape", 
"scale_ima")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `mapply`.

```
mapply(rweibull, n = 10L, shape = mat[,"shape"], scale = mat[,"scale_ima"])
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain what the 1:30, 15, 2 means? and the 10L?

Comment: in `m`, those numbers mean I'm constructing a matrix with the numbers 1 to 30 with 15 rows and two columns.  That matrix is intended to represent your 10000 row matrix as an example.  10L is the `n` argument to `rweibull` The L means I'm creating an integer value

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, so i already have the matrix like this: matrix <- cbind(shape,scale) , how can i modify it to fit your code?

Comment: thanks, when i do that i get> Error in matrix[, "scale"] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: So, class(mat) is matrix an dim(mat) is [1] 10000     2

Comment: thanks for the reply, i already edited the matrix name and i still get that

Comment: Ah, it was my problem, i solved it, thank you very much, i did a mistake at naming the scale

Comment: @1n1 -I made an edit.  The names were different.  It should work now

Comment: Note that you can also use `shape = mat[,1]` and `scale = mat[,2]` but I like to use the names to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Although I thought `rowwise` operations are more natural with `apply`, `mapply` seems to be bit faster

```
apply(mat, 1, function(x) rweibull(10, shape=x[1], scale=x[2]))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(42)
 mat2 <- cbind(shape=rnorm(1e6, 1, 0.05), scale_ima=rnorm(1e6, 0.1, 0.05))

 f1 <- function() mapply(rweibull, n = 10L, shape = mat2[,"shape"], scale = mat2[,"scale_ima"])
 f2 <- function() apply(mat2, 1, function(x) rweibull(10L, shape=x[1], scale=x[2]))

 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(f1(),f2(), unit="relative", times=25L)
 #    Unit: relative
 # expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 #f1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    25
 #f2() 1.373051 1.323128 1.293284 1.335026 1.994696    25
```

Comment: It's nice that you got an upvote for showing that my answer is faster, yet I didn't get one.  SO voting is so weird!  It's like people don't even read the answers

Comment: @Richard Scriven +1.  Actually, I got the vote before showing the benchmarks.  So, I don't know why they voted.